# Table of struct allocate C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

This is my structure:

```
typedef struct wyraz{

    char *slowo;
    char *tlumaczenie;
    struct wyraz *nastepny;

}WYRAZ;

typedef struct lista_tlumaczen{
    char znak;
    WYRAZ *lista_znakowa;
}LISTA_TLUMACZEN;
```

I want to have something like that

```
LISTA_TLUMACZEN tab[5];
```

but dynamic allocation I don't know how to do this, can someone help me?

Comment: You tagged this with `malloc`. So?

Comment: `LISTA_TLUMACZEN **tab = malloc(sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN *) * 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have embedded pointers to structures you need to think of memory allocation in layers. Starting at the highest level first in this case works best. So start with:

```
LISTA_TLUMACZEN tab[5];
```

Here you're saying you want a table of p`LISTA_TLUMACZEN` structures. If you want this to be dynamic, then you need a pointer to a `LISTA_TLUMACZEN`:

```
LISTA_TLUMACZEN *tab;
```

Then to allocate it, you need to determine how big it is. In this case, we'll say `NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS`:

```
tab = (LISTA_TLUMACZEN *)malloc(sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN) * 5);
```

If you want to be especially safe that the `malloc` parameter isn't out of range you can use:

```
tab = (LISTA_TLUMACZEN *)(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS <= (SIZE_MAX / sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN)) ? malloc(sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN) * 5) : NULL);
```

Now we have the dynamically allocated equivalent of your `tab[5]` data declaration. Note that it's a table of `LISTA_TLUMACZEN` structures. So the amount of memory to allocate is the product of 5 and the size of the structure.

Your `LISTA_TLUMACZEN` structure also has a pointer to another structure with more pointers. You can allocate those following the same kind of logic or actually only as needed when the program needs them and freeing them when they're no longer needed (which is the reason for having dynamic allocation). If all you do is pre-allocate everything with `malloc` then there's no point and you may as well statically declare everything.

Comment: int inicializuj_liste_tlumaczen(LISTA_TLUMACZEN ***glowa)
    {
     int i;
     *glowa = (LISTA_TLUMACZEN**)malloc(sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN*) * ILOSC_LITER);
     
     for ( i = 0; i < ILOSC_LITER; i++ )
      *glowa[i] = (LISTA_TLUMACZEN*)malloc( sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN) );
     
    }

    LISTA_TLUMACZEN  **lista = NULL;
    
    inicializuj_liste_tlumaczen(&lista);

this is the function to allocate memory but it doesnt work, why?

Comment: @Mr.Nimelo, You changed your original code in the problem statement such that my answer no longer corresponded to your problem statement. I have corrected my response above. This allocation function you are showing has a few problems. Firstly, the function you declared accepts, as a parameter, a `LISTA_TLUMACZEN` structure. But you are passing it a `LISTA_TLUMACZEN ***` (pointer to pointer to pointer to `LISTA_TLUMACZEN`). You need to think through your code very carefully to understand what is a datum and what is a pointer or address of a datum and then make the code to match accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget you may need to perform a sanity check before doing a multiply to calculate a malloc size: `tab = (5 <= SIZE_MAX / sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN) ? malloc(sizeof(LISTA_TLUMACZEN) * 5) : NULL);`

Comment: @sh1, thanks that's a great suggestion (+1). I figured with the example I was in safe territory, but you've covered the general case nicely. I'll add it to the answer.